# Speed of a falling pencil

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, angular-velocity

If you balance a pencil of length $d$ on its tip, and let it fall, how do you compute the final velocity of its other end just before it touches the ground?

(Assume the pencil is a uniform one dimensional rod)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of kinetic energy in the pencil just before it touches the ground is equal to the gravitational potential energy it lost while falling. That quantity is easy to compute, being simply m*g*h, where h=d/2 (the center of mass of the pencil started at height d/2 and ends at height 0). If we assume the tip of the pencil hasn't moved (this becomes a much more complex problem if there is friction between the tip and the table, etc) then all of that energy is now rotational kinetic energy, which is equal to 1/2*I*ω. I is the moment of inertia (1/12*m*d^2) and ω is the angular velocity. You know d, the mass terms cancel out, and once you solve for angular velocity you can determine linear velocity of the end.

Comment: If there is no friction, then how exactly do you propose that the tip will not move?

Comment: Ah OK thanks I forgot to use rotational kinetic energy

Comment: But wouldn't the axis of rotation be at the tip of the pencil so I=((1/3)md^2)?

Comment: @joshphysics I meant we would ignore motion entirely, friction notwithstanding.

Comment: @AdamDai that's a good point.