# Linear speed of falling pencil

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

> *Find the final linear speed of pencil. Pencil would move because of gravity. Let's assume that it is balancing on the tip. We do not take friction into consideration. – Given $$d=0.15m$$*

[Similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74886/)

---

My try:

$$E_{pot}=mgh$$
where $$h=\frac{d}{2}$$
$$E_{kin}=\frac{1}{2}*J*\omega$$
where $$J=\frac{1}{12}*m*d^{2}$$
Getting equation:
$$m*g*\frac{d}{2}=\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{12}m*d^{2}*\omega$$
next
$$\omega=\frac{12g}{d}=784\frac{rad}{s}$$
$$\upsilon=\frac{\omega}{2\pi}=124.7\frac{m}{s}$$
The right answer is $$2.1\frac{m}{s}$$
What's wrong here?

Comment: Right now it's not clear why the pencil would move at all. Please add some more information.

Comment: Pencil would move because of gravity. Let's assume that it is balancing on the tip. We do not take friction into consideration.

Comment: $E_{kin} \ne \frac{1}{2}*I*\omega$

Comment: Please edit Your question and add this information. Possibly some more informations because it is still not clear to me why You use certain formulas.

Comment: Also $I \ne \frac{1}{12}*m*d^{2}$. That's the expression for a thin rod hinged in the middle not at the end.

Comment: Apart from that it looks fine :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie, I tried to folow this solution http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74886/speed-of-a-falling-pencil

Comment: The $J$ for thin rod hinged in the middle is $J=2mr^{2}$. Right?

Comment: $E_{kin}=\frac{J\omega^{2}}{2}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't normally answer a homework question, but your working is basically correct and after all it was an [accepted answer here on the Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74886/speed-of-a-falling-pencil) that has led you astray.

Your working is fine, but the rotational kinetic energy is:

$$ T = \tfrac{1}{2} I \omega^2 $$

so you have missed the power of two. The [moment of inertia of a thin rod hinged at one end](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mi2.html) is:

$$ I = \tfrac{1}{3} m l^2 $$

Equate the change in potential energy to the rotational kinetic energy and use $v = r\omega$ and you'll end up with:

$$ v = \sqrt{3gl} $$

Putting in $g= 9.81 \, \mathrm{m\,s^{-2}}$ gives me $v = 2.10 \, \mathrm{m\,s^{-1}}$.